# setting active class and removing it from all others

Tags: jquery

I've got a couple of divs to scroll between. I need to set the one in active view (after a link was clicked) to 'active' and all the other div's should have that class removed.

Using toggle I can't get it to work.

```
$('.projecten').click(function () {
$('#due').toggleClass('selected'),
    $paneTarget.stop().scrollTo('#due', 800, {
        margin: true,
        onAfter: function () {
            $("body").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#1f8311"
            }, 800),projectenfade();
        }
    }); menuShow(),titleFadeOut();
});
```

the html

```
<div id="due" class="elements">
                    <h3 class="resizeme">...</h3>
                </div>
<div id="otto" class="elements">
                    <h3 class="resizeme">...</h3>
                </div>
<div id="etc" class="elements">
                    <h3 class="resizeme">...</h3>
                </div>

...

<div id="menu">

<p>
        <a class="welkom pointme">Welkom</a> <a class="blog pointme">Blog</a> <a class="media pointme">Media</a> <a class="projecten pointme">Projecten</a> <a class="contact pointme">Contact</a> 
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML as well.

Comment: Do you want to scroll to the "selected" div?

Comment: @ Matthew: the selected attribute is for resizing purposes. The active class (the one in view) needs to have the selected attribute to stay in view if the browser window is resized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why not just use addClass and removeClass:

```
$(".selected").removeClass("selected"); 
$(this).addClass("selected");
```

to only remove `selected` from divs use this for the first line:

```
$("div.selected").removeClass("selected");
```

Comment: Does this completely remove the class from all divs?

Comment: The above example will remove the class everywhere.  If you just want to remove it from divs change the selector to this: `div.selected`

Comment: I had too replace "this" with the actual name of the div, I think that's because "this" doesn't refer to the div in this case, but to the class (".projecten") Thanks a million!